# C sockets, jpeg image not displaying properly

Tags: c, sockets

I'm learning about sockets and Im in the process of creating a socket server which can serve html files, as well as images in the `jpeg` format. Based on other similar posts I've found, I can't deduce what I'm doing wrong. I use `fseek` and `ftell` to get the size of the image, and then I use `fread` to read those bytes into a `malloc`'ed character array, which I then send back. What am I doing wrong?

code for dealing with `jpeg` files:

```
else if (!strcmp(getFileExtension(fname), "jpg") || !strcmp(getFileExtension(fname), "jpeg"))
      {
        printf("got a jpeg request\n");
        FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "rb");

        if (fp == NULL)
        {
          perror("Error opening .jpg/.jpeg file");
          status = 500;
          ret = toStr(status);
          statusMessage = " Internal Server Error\n";
          body = "<h1>Server encountered error trying to open jpeg file</h1>";
          mode = html;
          goto shutdown;
        }

        // seek to end of file and get
        // length of the file to read
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        bodySize = ftell(fp);
        printf("file is %d bytes\n", bodySize);

        // seek back to beginning of file
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        // allocate and read len amt of bytes
        char *data = malloc(bodySize);
        fread(data, sizeof(char), bodySize, fp);
        fclose(fp);

        status = 200;
        ret = toStr(status);
        statusMessage = " OK\n";
        body = data;
        mode = jpeg;
        goto shutdown;
    }
```

my `shutdown` code, which simply sets the headers, status codes, etc. The jpeg file data should be within the `body` variable

```
    // cleanup and closing
    shutdown:
      // send just the headers first
      size = strlen(header) + strlen(ret) + strlen(statusMessage) + strlen(mode) + 1;
      reply = (char *)malloc(size);
      reply[size - 1] = '\0';
      snprintf(reply, size, "%s%s%s%s", header, ret, statusMessage, mode);
      printf("\n%s\n\n", reply);
      send(new_sd, reply, size, 0);

      // send just body
      if (!strcmp(mode, jpeg)) // jpeg uses bodySize
      {
        printf("body size (%d):\n%s\n", bodySize, body);
        send(new_sd, body, bodySize, 0);
      }
      else // non jpeg uses strlen
      {
        printf("body size (%d):\n%s\n", (int)strlen(body), body);
        send(new_sd, body, strlen(body), 0);
      }

      shutdown(new_sd, SHUT_RDWR);
      close(new_sd);
      exit(0);
```

Here is my server response to the browser(client):

[image]

Comment: Probably shouldn't be treating the jpeg data like it was a string...

Comment: Agreed - check what `strlen(body)` is actually evaluating to in your `shutdown` code. My guess is 4, given the server response. When `strlen` hits a `0`, it will return - your JPEG data might have many `0` characters within. You could use your `len` variable from earlier for this purpose instead.

Comment: Or you could just first send the headers and then send the body avoiding copying the image data

Comment: I have took @vmt's suggestion and am now sending body and headesr separately. I've also stopped using strlen for jpeg binary files. I have updated my post to reflect this code. The jpeg file still isnt displaying properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is no logistical issue to my edited post's code. The problem was that in the shutdown code, when I send the HTTP header reply, I used size as the length for the reply, when I should have used `strlen(reply)` or `size - 1` for `send(new_sd, reply, size, 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing stands out to me in terms of the socket code. Instead of this being a socket (only) issue, maybe it is (also) a protocol issue? Possibly a non-compliance issue with the HTTP/1.1 ([RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230)+) ?
neither Content-Length nor Transfer-Encoding specified? bad line endings? (status line would normally end with OK\r\n not OK\n\n)

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't use `snprintf` with `%s` for binary data like jpeg bytes, I believe `%s` terminates at null byte (0x00) which makes the binary file corrupt.

Also `strlen(body)` won't work either as strlen will also terminate at null byte (0x00) giving bad length for the jpeg data.

Try `memcpy` instead.

Open the file with this mode `"rb+"`

Simple pseudo-code (might not compile)

```
int jpegDataSize = len;
char* jpegdata = data;
reply_size = strlen(HEADER) + strlen(ret) + strlen(statusMessage) + strlen(mode) + jpegDataSize + 1; //can't use strlen for jpeg because it's binary
reply = (char *)malloc(reply_size);
memcpy(&reply[0], HEADER, strlen(HEADER));
memcpy(&reply[strlen(HEADER)], ret, strlen(ret));
memcpy(&reply[strlen(ret)], statusMessage, strlen(statusMessage));
memcpy(&reply[strlen(statusMessage)], mode, strlen(mode));
memcpy(&reply[strlen(mode)], jpegdata, jpegDataSize); //avoid strlen(jpegdata)
reply[reply_size - 1] = '\0';
printf("\n-------------------------------------\nresponse is (%d): \n%s\n\n", reply_size, reply); //can't use strlen (because jpegdata is binary)
send(new_sd, reply, reply_size, 0); //can't use strlen because jpegdata is binary.
shutdown(new_sd, SHUT_RDWR);
close(new_sd);
exit(0);
```

Comment: I have taken @vmt's suggestion from another comment to send the header and body separately, so using `snprintf` should be fine since it's only for the HTTP header/status code/msg/content type.